# C# Timer: change interval to infinite while periodic task is running

Tags: c#, timer, intervals

I want to know what happens if I set a timer interval to inifinite, while the timer is active. What happens if the periodic task is running at the time I set the interval to inifinite? Will it be block? Is it better to call stop method() and call start again whenever I want it?

I am writing data to a StreamWriter periodically, I use the same stream writer inside the periodic task that the timer performs, and in another place of my code (in both places I'm synchronizing the code with lock with the same object). If I comment the code on the periodic task (left it empty) everything goes fine, but when I let it run, the code outside the periodic task that is writing to the stream writer and gets blocked. It seems that the stream writer is unable to return from the write line method. I think setting the timer interval to inifinite is causing this issue.

Periodic task :

```
lock(object)
{
    sw.WriteLine("@@@")
}
```

Another thread:

```
timer.Change(Timeout.Infinite, Timeout.Infinite);
lock(object)
{  sw.WriteLine("@@@") //Thread is blocking here when the code in the timer delegate is executed.
}
```

I think timer.Change can be causing the timer thread to leave the sw in a non consistent state so the call to WriteLine after changing the interval never ends the execution

By the way, the stream writer is writing to a Pipeline between two different processes, but I don't think that matters on this scenario

Thank you

Comment: If I understood your case well, I believe you think of separation of responsibilities and parallelism.

Comment: Well, I 'm not sure what you mean with "separation of responsabilities". I will describe better the propose: When I write some data outside the periodic task, I don't want the periodic task to send data, so I temporary change the interval to infinite. I think it will be enough with the lock (I can't try it now because I am outside the work at the moment). So I wanted to know if changing the interval on the fly can cause the periodic delegate method to abruptly stop or it will let it finish as expected